# SpringBoot, Maven, Lombok StackOverflowErrorESC

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, lombok

I have maven project that success build on Windows environment.

```
C:\java\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn -DskipTests=true package -P prod
```

Build success

but when I've tried to execute the same command on Ubuntu env

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project ics3: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.StackOverflowError -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project ics3: Fatal error compiling

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1220)

Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill (JavacAST.java:506)
```

I've tried to set without luck the same memory to maven as on Windows PC

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx3096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

and `export JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx4g"`

my pom.xml is

```
  <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Java 11, SpringBoot 2.7

Comment: Lombok hooks into the compiler, and these things may happen. Can you do without Lombok?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that triggers that Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -Xss1024m" fixed issue. even -Xss1024k was enought.